# Excel 2016 custom number format

Tags: excel, format, numbers

I have a column where I would like to enter a string of 10 characters (either numbers or letters or mixed), i.e. `XXXXXXXXXX`, that is displayed as `XXXXX-XXXXX`. If I only type in numbers, I know that I can use the custom number format `00000-00000`, but I can't seem to get it to work with letters also. I've tried adding a `@` in the number format code at different places with no luck.

If possible and if the input is only 5 characters long, i.e. `XXXXX`, I would like for the cell to be able to automatically add a predefined prefix, `YYYYY`, so that the cell now contains the string `YYYYYXXXXX` and displays it as `YYYYY-XXXXX`.

That is, the column only contains strings with the length of 10 characters and they are all to be displayed as `XXXXX-XXXXX`. If I input 5 characters, then the cells in the column should add `YYYYY` as a prefix, if possible. However, the first part of my problem is the most important.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't do that with _formats_.  You'd have to change the actual cell value by inserting the `-`, which you can do with VBA with the Change event

Comment: I think you will need to use conditional formatting to get this one working. I can't really test properly on my phone, if your own research didn't resolve it I'll post an answer later

Comment: @LJ01 what _Format_ would you have the CF'g apply? AFAIK it's impossible to format a _string_ like this

Comment: @chris, that's correct on further analysis... Conditional formatting will handle part2 fine, not part 1

Comment: @chris neilsen Is it because I want to mix numbers and letters that it can't be done with a number format code?

Comment: @smlange yes.  If it were a number, then formatting could do it.

Comment: Alright, thanks for your comments!